# remove Purchase lines ordering by item no

Tags: erp, navision

I have the page of purchase order. In this pages I have a page included with lines, the purchase lines

[image]

The problem I'm facing is in each order i'm making the purchase lines are being sorted by item no, and it's a mess when I want to persist a order of my products and check each one and don't want to alter it's order understand? So in my both cases no order was the best scenario.

I have a lot of keys in the purchase lines table, but for the purchase order at the moment i don't have anything in "SourceTableView". What can I do? In the images below you can see the same product in different lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the PK for the Purchase Line in Standard NAV is Document Type,Document No.,Line No. so your List Page should show the lines in the correct order if the Key in the SourceTableView is empty.
However if your lines are still out of order there should be some code in the OnOpePage trigger.

Cheers

Comment: In SourcetableView I have SORTING(No.) ORDER(Ascending) WHERE(Document Type=FILTER(Order)), but the problem is when entering quantitiy for the item, it automatiically order the product list and my idea is to preserve the order.. so I want "no order" in this lines, in this specific page.

Comment: that's the issue, please remove the SORTING and ORDER bits

Comment: Without that, by your comment I thought that I will have the table order by Document Type,Document No.,Line No.. I don't want either this ... I don't wanna any order at all in this lines, in this specific page

Comment: I remove that and now SourceTableView is empty, although the items are order by item no ...